# object orientechnologies is not a member of package com?

Tags: scala, orientdb, apache-zeppelin

I have an OrientDB database and I want to import it into scala within Zeppelin. I'm following the example provided [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Scala-Language.html)
. However when I run the following command on Zeppelin's notebook

```
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery
```

I got this error:

```
<console>:27: error: object orientechnologies is not a member of package com
     import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId
```

but it looks `orientechnologies` is a member of `com`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi @MTT Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that zeppelin does not recognize some of the libraries and you need to add them separately. Here is the code I used to add jar file in Zeppelin:

```
%dep
z.load("/home/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.5.5-incubating-bin-all.orientdb-core-0.9.23.jar")
```

Make sure to restart Zeppelin before running the code. These lines need to be inserted before Spark initiation.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to reproduce your problem with class ORecordId in Scala and it works for me.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I said I'm using Scala in Zeppelin. Something is wrong in Zeppelin. If we do not use Zeppelin, it works for me as well.